# How can I append something into an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I would like to append some text into a input field.
I tried following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("input").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text">This is a paragraph.</input>

  <button id="btn1">Append text</button>

</body>

</html>
```

But it doesn't do anything. When I click on "Append Text", nothing happends.
So, how can I append something to an input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to append to the value of an input in `JQuery` is to use the `.val()` function. Also, it is better to use an `id` to select the input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#inp").val($("#inp").val()+" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="inp">This is a paragraph.</input>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of an Input Field you should use the `val` method on after you have select that element. and pass as argument the new value which you want to fill in that input element

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
   $('#paragraphField').val('This is the new value');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="paragraphField" type="text">This is a paragraph</input>

<button type="button" id="btn1">Append text</button>
```

The `append` method is use when you want to insert element as a child of another element.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
  $('.parent').append('<h2>new child</h2>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <p>this will contain all inserted element</p>
</div>


<button type="button" class="btn">Append Child</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .val() in jquery like

```
 $("input").val("<b>Appended text</b>.");
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` tags are not meant to have content between them. So, you should instead do:

```html
<input type="text" value="This is a paragraph." />
```

With that, you can use an `onclick` event like so:

```html
<button id="btn1" onclick="$('input').val($('input').val() + ' <b>Appended text</b>.')">Append Text</button>
```

Code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" value="This is a paragraph." />

<button id="btn1" onclick="$('input').val($('input').val() + ' <b>Appended text</b>.')">Append Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `val` method to populate text within an input field.

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#input").val(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="input">This is a paragraph.</input>

<button id="btn1">Append text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you append any text between `<input></input>` it will not be visible. You can only give value to input tag if you want to display any text in input.

When you give any text between input open and close tag in html browser automatically converts that like this..

```
<input type="text">This is a paragraph.</input>
```

Converted to

```
<input type="text"></input>
This is a paragraph.
```

But this is only applicable for static html. Browser is not able to convert dynamic text added using JQuery.

In your example you appending right way. After click on Append Text button, when you see the html using inspect element you will see this

```
 <input type="text"><b>Appended text</b>.</input>
 This is a paragraph.
```

But Appended text is not visible because it's inside input tag.

So technically it's anything inside input tag is not visible. You have to give value to input if you want to display it in input.

To set value of input using jquery you can use this

```
$("input").val("any text");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's soo simple but none other answer are correct to the point.
These are little corrections:

1. `.append` is used to add any text to paired tags. So use `.val()` instead.
2. Input tag is singular tag so there's no need for `</input>` . Value inside input will be decided by value parameter inside input tag. `<input type="text" id="inp" value="This is a paragraph.">`.

So the final code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("input").val( $("input").val() + " Appended text" );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="inp" value="This is a paragraph.">
<button id="btn1">Append text</button>

</body>
</html>
```